# How to get the parent which contains the least of children?

Tags: jquery, dom

We have two containers next to each other, with containers inside them.

```
<ul class="containers">
    <li>Matt</li>
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Mark</li>
</ul>
<ul class="containers">
    <li>Roger</li>
    <li>Bill</li>
    <li>Lara</li>
    <li>Miriam</li>
    <li>Dylan</li>
    <li>Harry</li>
</ul>
```

What is the most **optimized** method, for understanding and retrieving the "container", with least children inside it?

Comment: If you're looking for the *fastest* solution, you have checked the wrong answer. My solution is approximately 10 times faster. Here is a performance comparison: http://jsperf.com/comparing-two-child-element-counters

Comment: @Codemonkey, yes you are right, however I was looking for the fastest solution in jQuery and not in native JS.

Comment: My solution also uses jQuery to select the elements and you can easily wrap the resulting element in a jQuery object for the same results as the accepted answer. It difference does it make, when the solution is wrapped in a function, if the function uses native JavaScript or slow jQuery functions on the inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $el = $('ul.containers:first');

$('ul.containers').each(function(){
  if( $(this).children().length < $(this).next('ul.containers').children().length ){
    $el = $(this);
  }
});

console.log( $el ); //$el is now the parent with the least children.
```

or a slightly shorter version with the single line if:

```
var $el = $('ul.containers:first');

$('ul.containers').each(function(){
  $el = $(this).children().length < $(this).next('ul.containers').children().length ? $(this) : $el ;
});

console.log( $el ); //$el is now the parent with the least children.
```

Comment: Very nice, you understood my "retrieving" part perfectly.

Comment: However, what happens, if there are more then two parent containers?

Comment: It iterates over **every** UL element and compares the number of children. Number is not an issue. Using jQuery's `each` function is not as fast as a native loop though. Also wrapping `this` in a jQuery element to count the children instead of checking the number directly could be considered wasteful

Comment: @Codemonkey: How would you count the children directly?

Comment: @MoinZaman - you could use `this.childNodes.length` but it would give you a different number as it counts textnodes etc. aswell. I think just using jQuery is fine for this purpose. +1

Comment: I think you still need the ul.containers:first for $el default, since it acts as a fallback element, in case both containers have same amount of children.

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas: I just want to make sure - when you ask for the most "optimized" method for achieving this result, do you not mean performance-wise? I can assure you that while the solution in this answer sure is elegant and straight-forward, it is **far** from performance optimized.

Comment: @MoinZaman: Regarding your question, you can use `element.childElementCount`. Check my answer

Answer (score 2):

Avoiding unnecessary closures and iterating using a for loop, this should perform quite nicely. I'm pretty certain that this solution is faster than Moin Zaman's code. Not as pretty though - depends on whether or not you need maximum performance.

```
var containers = $('.containers');
var least_children = null;
var smallest_container = null;

for(var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++)
{
    var container = containers[i];

    if(least_children === null)
    {
        least_children = container.childElementCount;
        smallest_container = container;
    }
    else if(container.childElementCount < least_children)
    {
        least_children = container.childElementCount;
        smallest_container = container;
    }
};

// smallest_container now contains the UL with the least children as a
// HTMLElement
```

On JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BXnnL/3/

Comment: @MoinZaman: My solution is faster by a factor of 10: http://jsperf.com/comparing-two-child-element-counters

Comment: I think your solution is definitely faster.